# How to correct copy file from var using cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im trying to do backup .bat, the code i have:

```
set /p SourceCatalog="Input Source Catalog: "
set /p BackupCatalog="Input Backup Catalog: "
set /p FileName="Input a file name: "
cd "%BackupCatalog%"
    if not exist FileName (
        copy "%SourceCatalog%"%FileName% "%BackupCatalog%"
    )
```

in this line - `copy "%SourceCatalog%"%FileName% "%BackupCatalog%"` i have a mistake, it copies every files from the source folder. i tried do like `"%SourceCatalog%"\%FileName%` or `"%SourceCatalog%"\"%FileName%"` but its still not working correctly, so, what should i do to copy a single file using variable?

Comment: It should be `If Not Exist "%FileName%"`, not `if not exist FileName`. However, I see no point in changing directory, so simply `If Exist "%SourceCatalog%\%FileName%" If Not Exist "%BackupCatalog%\%FileName%" "%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe" "%SourceCatalog%\%FileName%" "%BackupCatalog%\" /KRHY` should suffice.

Comment: @Compo, is it better to specify `"%__appdir__%xcopy.exe"`?

Comment: I prefer to do so @lit, because unlike normal variables, its value cannot be modified, accidentally or otherwise. However it is not documented, and I've had infrequent reports of it not working on some systems. My scripts use it, but for those designed for a production environment, I do usually, check its validity first, and set it to "%SystemRoot%\System32\" if that fails.